# What makes a standout profile for applying to a top-ten ranked CS masters in the US?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, application

I'm currently an undergrad student, will complete it next 3 months, I was thinking that, what makes an undergrad profile different and stand out of crowd?

To be more specific: what does it take for an applicant for a Masters in Computer Science, for top 10 ranked departments in the United States.

What is it that an undergrad must do which will elevate his/her profile. Is research or publications expected from undergrads?

Comment: _What is it that an undergrad must do which will elevate his/her profile._ — Ask this question at least two years before graduation.  It's too late to do much now.

Comment: @JeffE What can a second year BSc student do to improve his/her profile/CV?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent (1) Talk to professors (yes plural), in person, especially about research. (2) Do something that displays your intellectual creativity and maturity and that is _not_ required by your classes.  Examples include graduate-level classes, independent study/research with faculty, industry internships, contributions to open-source projects, and posting on StackExchange sites.  (4) Don't screw up your classes.

Comment: @JeffE: Would that be okay if I ask you a personalized question?
I've led 2 Internships, 3 major projects, 3 mini-projects, 1 International publication (though I consider it as simply literature survey of that subject) and relatively less aggregate % (61%), would that be good enough for my profile?

Comment: That obviously depend on what you actually did in your internships, projects, and paper. The crucial point is the phrase _displays your intellectual creativity and maturity_. It's not a checklist.

Comment: That I utterly agree on this, but how can one show this to anyone without having a direct interaction with the admission committee?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have little time to do a huge number of things, but a few things you can do:

- contribute to some open source projects there are many many and all need help of at level
- show that you have played with some ideas on GitHub
- show you can turn your hand to many languages again stick it up on GitHub
- have a shot at project Euler, and stick it all up on Github
- build an App or website that does something/anything

Publications for Undergrads are great, but not really expected.